# How to get string between start and end character in C#

Tags: c#

How to get substring of string like file_{AAA}_{BBB}.xml ?

My Code:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, "{(.*)}"); result.ToList().ForEach(x => MessageBox.Show(x));
```

Result :

```
AAA
BBB
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, Please  string[] result = Regex.Split(str, "{(.*)}");
                result.ToList().ForEach(x => MessageBox.Show(x));

Comment: Put it in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Please define the question more precisely.
Like: Is the string length, the prefix, the prefix length or the length of the wanted result fix?
Is {AAA} a single char or a string itself? (as you refer to chars in the question title)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string str = "file_{AAA}_{BBB}.xml";
var regex = new Regex("(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})");
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
```

Comment: Thanks so must. But the result are : {AAA} {BBB}, i would like AAA and BBB.

Answer (score 0):

Super ghetto, I suck at regex and you should probably use Rahul's answer instead, but:

```
string f = "file_{AAA}_{BBB}.xml";
string o = String.Empty;

while (f.Contains('{') && f.Contains('}'))
{
    int openIndex = f.IndexOf('{');
    int closeIndex = f.IndexOf('}');

    o += f.Substring(openIndex + 1, closeIndex - openIndex - 1) + " ";
    f = f.Remove(0, closeIndex + 1);
}

o.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Will output `AAA BBB`

Answer (score 0):

Original from Rahul Tripathi, just added removing of {}

```
        string str = "file_{AAA}_{BBB}.xml";
        var regex = new Regex("{.*?}");
        var matches = regex.Matches(str);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            result.Add(item.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may follow that:

string filename = string.Format(@"{0}", Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
string filepath = "f:\ClientDocument\" + Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            int fileLength = (fileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength) / 1024;